# Run abaqus inp file with abaqus from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, abaqus

I am trying to run abaqus inp file and process it with abaqus from python and get the output. It is not working. How can it be done?

```
import os
import subprocess

inp = 'C:/Users/sel/Desktop/My work/Python Abaqus/New folder (2)/Job-1.inp'
abaqus = r'C:/SIMULIA/Abaqus/Commands/abq6145.bat'
subprocess.Popen("%s %s" % (abaqus, inp))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture stdout and strerr of a subprocess through the `run` function of the subprocess module by setting the `capture_output` keyword argument to `True`. This should work.

```
inp = 'C:/Users/sel/Desktop/My work/Python Abaqus/New folder (2)/Job-1.inp'
abaqus = r'C:/SIMULIA/Abaqus/Commands/abq6145.bat'
cp = subprocess.run([abaqus, inp], capture_output=True)
cp.stdout
```

Comment: I am getting this error:

b'Abaqus Error: Command line option "C:/Users/sel/Desktop/My work/Python Abaqus/New folder (2)/Job-1.inp" may not be used with "analysis".\r\n              Valid options for use with "analysis" are:\r\n[\'after\', \'background\', \'convert\', \'convert_sdi\', \'cpus\', \'csedirector\', \'domains\', \'double\', \'dynamic_load_balancing\', \'field\', \'fil\', \'globalmodel\', \'help\', \'history\', \'host\', \'information\', \'input\', \'interactive\', \'job\', \'madymo\', \'memory\',

Comment: \'mp_host_split\', \'mp_mode\', \'listenerport\', \'oldjob\', \'order_parallel\', \'output_precision\', \'parallel\', \'port\', \'performance_summary\', \'performance_summary_detail\', \'queue\', \'scratch\', \'standard_parallel\', \'timeout\', \'user\']\r\n\r\nAbaqus/Analysis exited with error(s).\r\n'

Comment: `Abaques Error` seems like an error with Abaqus. I'm not familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

You're in the wrong directory and you're not specifying the job correctly. The correct command line syntax to start solving c:\temp\whatever.inp file is:

```
cd \temp
abaqus job=whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this way might help you:

First, prepare your .inp file (the initial simulation: mySim.inp)

Second, in a python script (let's call it RunSim.py) write:

```
from subprocess import check_output
check_output("abaqus job=mySim.inp double cpus=4 interactive", shell=True)
```

You can change **cpus** depending on your computer.

Third, add also this line:

```
check_output("abaqus cae noGUI=odb_reader.py", shell=True)
```

Forth, in the odb_reader.py, you should write a function to read the odb file and save the result a csv file. If you want to do an optimization, you can then open this csv file in the RunSim,py file and extracted the value that you want as the objective function.

So if you want to iteratively run RunSim.py file, you may need also to delete the scratch file after each iteration. You can use this:

```
os.remove("mySim.sim")
```

...

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me:

```
import subprocess
import os

job_name = "Job-Name" # set job name without file extension (i.e. do not include .inp)
num_cpus = "4" # specify number of cpus
ask_delete = "OFF" # if u want it to delete old job files specify "ON"

new_dir = r"-path-to-folder-containing-job-file"
os.chdir(new_dir)

subprocess.run(["abaqus", "job=" + job_name, "cpus=" + num_cpus, "int", "ask_delete=" + ask_delete],shell=True)
```

Hope it helps